# Makefile to execute a sequence of steps

Tags: makefile

I use make to execute a series of process steps. Each step depends on the success of the previous one. Once completed a step, I touch a file with the name of the step into a separate directory.

Here is one example to explain the concept:

```
VPATH=steps

step1:
        @echo "do some actions with $@"
        @touch $(VAPTH)/$@

step2: step1
        @echo "do some actions with $@"
        @touch $(VPATH)/$@

step3: step2
        @echo "do some actions with $@"
        @touch $(VPATH)/$@
```

It basically works, however there is a weakness: it checks for targets either in "." and in VPATH. If you erroneously touch ./step1 in the working directory "." make gets confused. I'd like to know if I can avoid any ambiguity on checking the targets/prerequisites, but I'd like to keep using

```
make step3
```

and not

```
make steps/step3
```

Any other Makefile example to get the same objective is welcome. Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A fundamental rule of makefiles is that you cannot create targets that are different from what makes thinks they should be.  Make puts the name of the target that it wants you to build in the `$@` variable.  Your rule *must* create a target with that name, or make will not work properly.  In your example you're creating a target with the name `$(VPATH)/$@` which is not the same as `$@`, so that's not right.

Another rule of makefiles is that VPATH cannot be used (correctly) to find derived targets.  It can only be used to find source files.

I recommend you change the variable name from `VPATH` to something like `STEPDIR`, just to avoid confusion.  Then you can write a makefile like this (note this is untested and may need to be tweaked).  Look up Static Pattern Rules in the GNU make manual to understand what I'm doing in the commented part:

```
STEPDIR := steps
STEPS := step1 step2 step3

# Translate from local to subdirectory
.PHONY: $(STEPS)
$(STEPS): %: $(STEPDIR)/%

$(STEPDIR)/step1:
        @...
        @touch $@

$(STEPDIR)/step2: $(STEPDIR)/step1
        @...
        @touch $@

$(STEPDIR)/step1: $(STEPDIR)/step2
        @...
        @touch $@
```